# Issue with Sorting a HTML Table Data Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've a table displaying table with static data and trying to sort using jquery.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#sortTable').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]]
    });
  });
```

HMTL:

```
<table class="table" id="sortTable" data-page-length="25">
<thead>
        <tr><th><b>name</b></th><th><b>number</b></th><th><b>Date</b></th></tr>
         </thead>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>10.1</td> <td>12/31/2015</td></tr>
   <tr><td>d</td><td>1.1</td> <td>12/1/2015</td></tr>
   <tr><td>a</td><td>2.3</td> <td>12/2/2015</td></tr>
   <tr><td>e</td><td>1.7</td> <td>12/3/2015</td></tr>
   <tr><td>f</td><td>9.1</td> <td>12/31/2016</td></tr>
</table>
```

When I click on the number to sort, the sorting is not right as it is treating number as a String, is there anyway that I can resolve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the [datetime-moment](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) plugin.

Load its dependencies into the DOM, under jquery and data-tables, but above the `jQuery(document).ready()` block:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

Load the plugin with the correct `12/1/2015` [date format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) before initializing dataTable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.fn.dataTable.moment( 'M/D/YYYY' ); // use MM if months have leading 0
    jQuery('#sortTable').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but If i want to sort on number, second column <td>10.1</td> ..how can we do this?